# String parameter not automatically parsing into bytes32 when used with form

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I have a solidity function which looks like this-

```
function issueCertificate(address _recipient, bytes32 _certi_name)
```

When I call the function using truffle console, I am able to run it using-

```
issueCertificate("0x0213e3852b8afeb08929a0f448f2f693b0fc3ebe", "random")
```

But when I run it using web3 and forms with same data in string format, it gives error-

> Error: Given parameter is not bytes: "random"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using web3.js version 1.0, you can wrap the string as shown here:

`web3.utils.asciiToHex("random")`

See the documentation here:

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#asciitohex

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
issueCertificate("0x0213e3852b8afeb08929a0f448f2f693b0fc3ebe", bytes32("random"))
```

Basically, wrap the string with bytes32()

Edit, missed the call being made from Web3 try:

```
issueCertificate("0x0213e3852b8afeb08929a0f448f2f693b0fc3ebe", web3.fromAscii("random"))
```

Basically, in Web3 wrap the string with web3.fromAscii()

Update:

Latest version uses:

```
issueCertificate("0x0213e3852b8afeb08929a0f448f2f693b0fc3ebe", web3.utils.fromAscii("random"))
```

Comment: There is no "bytes32()" in javascript.

Comment: Sorry, missed that you were calling it from web3 try wrapping the string with web3.fromAscii("random")

Comment: Thanks. It worked. It is "web3.utils.fromAscii" in latest version.

Comment: Deprecated again - use web3.utils.asciiToHex as suggested by the other answer